# Debug for multiple C++ files in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I think i entered all of the correct settings but it gave me a prelaunch task error because the program contains multiple files so i tried to correct the tasks.json settings and set args to "*.cpp" but i still have the same problem.
Note that all the files are in the same folder and that i have no errors during the compilation.

Prelaunch task error :

[image: Prelaunch task error]

After setting "*.cpp" in the args in tasks.json i still get the previous error + this :

[image: error]

launch.json settings :

```
{
    
    "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "args": [],
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
                "environment": [],
                "externalConsole": false, //set to true to see output in cmd instead
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\bin\\gdb.exe",
                "setupCommands": [
                    {
                        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    }
                ],
                "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
            },
            {
                "name": "g++ build & run active file",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "args": [],
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
                "environment": [],
                "externalConsole": false, //set to true to see output in cmd instead
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\bin\\gdb.exe",
                "setupCommands": [
                    {
                        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    }
                ],
                "preLaunchTask": "g++ build & run active file"
            }
        ]
    }
```

tasks.json settings :

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    
        "tasks": [
          {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
              "-g",
              "*.cpp",
              "-o",
              "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
              "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build & run active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
              "*.cpp",
              "-o",
              "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
              "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            }
          }
        ],
    
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the text that appears when you press the `Show Errors` button.

Comment: @KenY-N done , you have a solution ?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow please do you know a solution ?

Comment: Your source files must be in a subdirectory.

Comment: @ABacker the "include"s must be inside the "main" in the code ?

Comment: What do you mean 'the includes'? I mean that your source code are in the working directory's subdirectory, say project/src/main.cpp, which should be at project/main.cpp.

Comment: @ABacker they are all in the same folder

Comment: Can you show me your file tree? Run `tree` command in your project folder.

Comment: @ABacker i don't know how to comment pictures ( if that's possible ), anyway my project folder contains 2 folders :   ".vscode" and "test" , the first one contains the json files above , and the seconde folder contains the cpp files used in the program

Comment: That's the problem, you should move your cpp files in test directory to its parent folder, your project folder, which should be the working directory. Or you have to cd to test directory before you execute g++ cmd.

Comment: @ABacker now it's giving me launch json error

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample settings

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/api.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/",
            "environment": [],
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-Wall",
                "-o",
                "api.exe",
                "*.cpp"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

File tree should be like this

```
project           <- this is the working directory
    |--.vscode/
          |--*.json
    |--main.cpp
    |--other.cpp
    |--main.exe     <- this is the executable compiled by your task json
```

So the executable path should be `${workspaceFolder}/main.exe`.

Comment: launch: program 'c:\Users ... \test\main.exe' does not exist

Comment: but no errors when compiling

Comment: If there were no errors while compiling, you need to verify the location of the executable in the windows file explorer. Perhaps your Antivirus deleted your executable or perhaps your problem is related to having a space in the path of the executable.

Comment: "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.exe", not `/test/main.exe`

Comment: @ABacker test is my workspace folder

Comment: I've ran into this problem with many iterations of VS IDE, so while trying to figure things out I recommend to  avoid using user directory if user name contains unicode (especially if that's odd language pages). Studio and cl.exe may fold on it, g++ may fold if user name language doesn't match its console locale set.